# Calling abort in C : does it release heap memory?

Tags: c, dynamic, malloc, abort

Calling abort() in C will cause abnormal termination of the process. I could find through online resources that it does not close open files, may not delete temporary files and may not flush stream buffer. How about dynamically allocated memory (allocated through malloc() function)? Are they reclaimed?

Answer (score 3):

When a program terminates (in a normal, hosted implementation of C), the memory the program used is freed.  It doesn't matter whether it terminates via `abort()` or via a normal exit.

If you're on an obscure (and hostile) embedded system, you might find the rules are different, but it is (AFAIK) unusual, even in freestanding implementations, for the memory not to be released when the program exits, regardless of how it exits.

Comment: The ordinary memory is freed, including memory allocated by the standard `malloc` family. Special things like named shared memory may persist.